# PHP verification data error

Tags: php, mysql

I have an problem with my PHP verification data.
This my code so far

```
$cek_saldo=mysql_query
("SELECT * FROM t_balance");

        while ($data_cek = mysql_fetch_array($cek_saldo));
        {
            $b_id = $data_cek['badge_id'];
            $mon = $data_cek['month'];
            $bal = $data_cek['balance_type'];
        }

        if ($b_id == '$badge_id' AND $mon == '$date_month' AND $b_type == '$jns_saldo')
        {
            echo "<div class='emp_err warn'>Balance for this month has been added before.</div>";
        }

        else
        {
            if($_POST)
            {
                $query = "INSERT INTO t_balance(badge_id, balance_amount, month, balance_type, date_transaction)
                        VALUES ('$badge_id', '$saldo', '$bulan', '$jns_saldo', '$date_transaction')
                ";
                $hasil = mysql_query($query);

                if($hasil)
                {

                    echo "<div class='emp_err success'>Balance transaction successfully added.</div>";
                }
                else
                {

                    echo "<div class='emp'>Gagal menambahkan saldo.</div>";
                }
            }
        }
```

The rule is :
Tabungan Wajib can be submit for 1 time per month. So if twice, it will give error : "Balance for this month has been added before."

Tabungan Tambahan can be submit more than 1 time per month. So if submit more than 1 time, it will saved.

Anyone have a suggestions ?

Comment: Are there any errors outputted? What is the behaviour you're experiencing & what are you expecting? Some clarification needed please.

Comment: Michael, what i have to do is prevent submit data twice if there is same data with badge_id, month and balance type. It just for Tabungan wajib rules. For Tabungan tambahan it can be submit many times

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: @HapshoutDotCom please check answer and reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($b_id == "$badge_id" AND $mon == "$date_month" AND $b_type == "$jns_saldo")
        {
            echo "<div class='emp_err warn'>Balance for this month has been added before.</div>";
        }
```

Your code failed due to the single quotes in the comparison using variables try to learn the difference between single and double quoted strings in php

Comment: what i want to do is prevent same data saved with balance type : tabungan wajib. if tabungan tambahan it will allowed for many times saved

Answer (score 0):

This validation will no work 
 reason being you are selecting multiple rows from database and assigning only the last on e to  `$b_id` .. `$mon` etc

and you are using `single quotes` for comparison

**RESOLUTION**

1. select data based on some id if you can

   ```
   $cek_saldo=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t_balance where id = 'someid'");

   while ($data_cek = mysql_fetch_array($cek_saldo));
   {
       $b_id = $data_cek['badge_id'];
       $mon = $data_cek['month'];
       $bal = $data_cek['balance_type'];
   }
   ```
2. set the error flag

   ```
   $error = false;

   while ($data_cek = mysql_fetch_array($cek_saldo));
   {
       $b_id = $data_cek['badge_id'];
       $mon = $data_cek['month'];
       $bal = $data_cek['balance_type'];
       if($b_id == $badge_id AND $mon == $date_month AND $b_type == $jns_saldo)
      {
         $error = true;
         break
      }
   }
    if($error)
    {
       echo "<div class='emp_err warn'>Balance for this month has been added before.</div>";

    }
   ```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to quote.I suppose `$badge_id` `$date_month` `$jns_saldo` come from your form with $_POST

```
if ($b_id == $badge_id AND $mon == $date_month AND $b_type == $jns_saldo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
$cek_saldo= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t_balance");

    while ($data_cek = mysql_fetch_array($cek_saldo));
    {
        $b_id = $data_cek['badge_id'];
        $mon = $data_cek['month'];
        $bal = $data_cek['balance_type'];

        if ($b_id == "$badge_id" && $mon == "$date_month" && $b_type == "$jns_saldo")
        {
            echo "<div class='emp_err warn'>Balance for this month has been added before.</div>";
        }
        else
        {
            if($_POST)
            {
                $query = "INSERT INTO t_balance(badge_id, balance_amount, month, balance_type, date_transaction)
                        VALUES ('".$badge_id."', '".$saldo."', '".$bulan."', '".$jns_saldo."', '".$date_transaction."')";
                $hasil = mysql_query($query);

                if($hasil)
                {

                    echo "<div class='emp_err success'>Balance transaction successfully added.</div>";
                }
                else
                {

                    echo "<div class='emp'>Gagal menambahkan saldo.</div>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```